# Need regex to match multiple string in HTML response

Tags: regex, f5

I'm trying to build a regex to match mutliple strings from an HTML response.
This is used to monitor a webpage from a load balancer. If the regex has a match, the load balancer will consider the server as UP and will send traffic.

Example of expected HTML response :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
X-AREQUESTID: *1KIRCWLx688x71065x0
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Wed, 31 Oct 2018 11:28:14 GMT
{"state":"RUNNING"}
```

What I want to achieve is trying to match `{"state":"RUNNING"}` OR `{"state":"MAINTENANCE"}` AND `HTTP/1.1 200`

So I have the following working *regexes*, but I don't know how to bundle them up together ;-)

- `\{\"state\":\"RUNNING\"\}|\{\"state\":\"MAINTENANCE\"\}`

will match `{"state":"RUNNING"}` OR `{"state":"MAINTENANCE"}`

- `HTTP\/1\.(0|1) (200|301|302)`

will match the HTTP response code 200, 301 or 302 (ex : `HTTP/1.1 200`)

So now, how do I build a mega regex will all conditions ?

`HTTP\/1\.(0|1) (200|301|302)` AND `\{\"state\":\"RUNNING\"\}|\{\"state\":\"MAINTENANCE\"\}` ?

Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
/HTTP\/1\.(0|1) (200|301|302).*?(\{\"state\":\"RUNNING\"\}|\{\"state\":\"MAINTENANCE\"\})/s
```

The key in this version is the `s` flag, which allows `.` to match a newline (`\n`) character. [**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/Y0EaTQ/2).

Another option, without using flags:

```
HTTP\/1\.(0|1) (200|301|302)[\s\S]*?(\{\"state\":\"RUNNING\"\}|\{\"state\":\"MAINTENANCE\"\})
```

The key is the `[\s\S]*?`, which matches literally anything (new lines included) in a non-greedy fashion. [**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/4McviY/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Combining two regular expressions is done by simply concatenating them. If you want to allow arbitrary characters in between, use `.*` between them.

Assuming that your regular expressions match over the whole response including headers and body and not just single lines, the following should suffice.

```
HTTP\/1\.(0|1) (200|301|302)\r\n(.*?)(\{\"state\":\"RUNNING\"\}|\{\"state\":\"MAINTENANCE\"\})$
```

Comment: Note that `.` does not match newline characters (`\n`) by default.